# How may I write good English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, writing-style, writing

I am a senior professional from India. I studied most of my educational career in English medium. For professional reasons and personal fervor I want to write good English. I am looking for expert suggestion. Web based free resources are slightly preferable.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately your question is not on-topic in this community. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here. If you have a question related with English Language and its Usage, you can always post a question here. But it should be on-topic. Happy holiday!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Comment: I recommend you read the Gospel of Mark in the Bible. There are many fine modern versions which are in readily understandable English, but the New King James Version (NKJV) might give you just enough challenge that your writing will improve if you emulate its style. When you are finished with Mark, you might try the more challenging Gospel of Matthew or the Gospel of John. Reading, writing, and speaking are all interrelated, but there is no substitute for writing regularly to improve your writing. With a good book on English grammar and style in hand, go to a site such as English Learners

Comment: on the Stack Exchange, and submit some answers to learners' questions. This effort alone will "force" you to analyze your writing and at the same time get "feedback" from others in the form of positive reinforcement if you provide good answers. Best wishes! Don

Comment: @rhetorician The NKJV Gospels?  What is that?  Some kind of cruel joke?

Comment: @deadrat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_King_James_Version

Comment: @rhetorician Reading widely is a good strategy.  Reading narrowly is not.

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, I get what it is and I know how to find it.  I just think it's terrible advice.

Comment: @ab2: If by "reading narrowly" you are implying that reading the perennial best seller in the entire world will somehow cripple a person intellectually, I politely disagree with you. If you want to think and speak intelligently about narrow-mindedness, I commend to you Alan Bloom's book, "The Closing of the American Mind." Bloom had no particular religious ax to grind, but he rightly recognized the treasure trove to be found in classic books, particularly the Bible. The KJV version is admittedly difficult for virtually any non-native English speaker, but the updated NKJV version is easier IMO.

Comment: @deadrat: Please check out my comment to ab2. A cruel joke? You must be kidding. There's an anecdote I heard  which involved folksingers Bob Dylan and Noel Paul Stookey. Dylan was asking Stookey (the "Paul" of Peter, Paul & Mary) about the existential angst he was feeling, so Stookey recommended to Dylan that he read the Bible. Interestingly, years later Stookey became a committed Christian. So did Dylan, for that matter, but I guess it didn't "take." Recommending the Bible to folks as a way to hone their English writing skills is anything but cruel; it's sage advice which can b life-changing.

Comment: @deadrat can you elaborate on why you think it is such terrible advice? It is good modern style writing, if a bit flowery, and the stories there are a good introduction to generally common Western cultural touch points. I mean Jane Austen is great, but is somewhat narrowly British.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure it's worth disputing another's taste in writing style, but the Gospels are written in koine, very simple vernacular Greek that would be understood by the greatest number of people.  The NKJV is true to that style and makes for plodding narrative of simple sentences.  I doubt it would help a senior professional.  The vocabulary is tied to the mythology of early Christianity, which isn't a religious "touch point" in Europe and which is more honored in the breach than the observance in the US.

Comment: @rhetorician I'd say the same thing about any single book or set of books in one category.  I agree there is a treasure trove in classic books, emphasis on the plural, and emphasis on a wide range of periods, authors, categories.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, good writers read a lot.  Read novels, history books, or whatever appeals to you.  Also try reading speeches by well-regarded speakers.  Many of the addresses by U.S. Presidents Abraham Lincoln, John F. Kennedy, Ronald Reagan and Bill Clinton are quite good.  Reading Ernest Hemmingway and Mark Twain are excellent for aspiring writers as well, in my humble opinion.  Recognize that some of Twain's characters are speaking in a local dialect that is somewhat obsolete.  O. Henry's "The Gift of the Magi" is a good starter, too.

Second, get a good book on writing style such as Strunk & White's book "The Elements of Style."

Third, a sense of humor is important.  Works by George S. Kaufman, Oscar Wilde, and collections of essays by Groucho Marx will give you a feel of how American-style wit, including puns, irony, and satire.

In fact, I will close with a quote from Groucho Marx:  "Outside of a dog, a book is a man's best friend.  Inside of a dog, it is too dark to read."  [That line is a twist on a common proverb:  "A dog is a man's best friend."  That line has been played with for years.  President Harry Truman is reported my many to have said, "If you want a friend in Washington, get a dog."]

Good luck with your education.

Comment: *The Elements of Style* isn't a grammar book.  As its title suggests, it's a book on writing style, portions of it outdated.  A sense of humor is important, especially on this site, but humor is very difficult to understand.  I'm not sure it's good advice to start there.

Comment: @deadrat That's why a non-native writer must read many types of books so he can learn our sense of humor.

Comment: Thank you. I try to read lot. Your examples are nice. I try to read editorials of good newspapers. Recently, I am trying to read  good article, see the main story, write the things on my own, compare and improve. I know I was slightly off topic but this was most reliable place I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my friends improved their English by watching movies and TV shows in English with English subs.  They said it helped with learning idioms and noticing certain patterns in English grammar such as tense and article usage.  Also, you can read English and listen to the spoken language at the same time.  But be sure to watch shows where the characters don't tend to make many grammar mistakes.   I would recommend Sherlock Holmes (both the movie and the TV show) to start.  I hope Netflix is available in India.

I hope this helps.

Marco Polo (Netflix show) is also great. Don't let their accents fool you, their English is awesome.

Comment: Just a heads-up. You need to read our help center once more to understand what questions and answers can be on-topic. It is also necessary for you to ask a better question.  The question above is off-topic because it can generate only primarily-opinion-based answers like yours without any reference/research. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Are experiences of friends not research?  Would you say you have experience or facts to support your conclusory statement that my comment was without research or reference? Watching movies with subtitles helps provide context to grammar rules. Understanding context helps one write.  Many of my friends can attest to that.  In fact, most fluent well versed non-native English speakers watch a lot of English films.

Comment: You don't understand my comment. You need to take some time to get used to this community. The question is blatantly off-topic and you are not supposed to answer this kind of question. Have you read [this part](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)? It says  **Not all questions can or should be answered here**. One example is **...are not about English language and usage as defined in the help center**. Read it more carefully. You will understand. Lastly, **experiences of your friends** can **never** be any research. If you have a question about this, read the help center.